# Problem after upgrading from 14.10 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

I have upgraded to 16.04 from 14.10. The updates were not completely done in the process, the update cleaning process did not run and when I restarted my laptop, it is not restarting normally. I see the error as shown below in the picture.

Note: If I click advance option there are lot of options and by selecting one of them I am able to access 16.04, but not directly.

[image]

Comment: Just to make it clearer: Have you upgraded from 14.10 via 15.04  via 15.10 to 16.04? As upgrading from 14.10 to 16.04 is officially not supported as far as i know (while upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 is - LTS to LTS)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest booting into one of the alternative versions of 16.04 that you can get into and try running `sudo update-grub`.

You may also want to run `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and `sudo do-release-upgrade` to see if those fix the incomplete update.

Comment: While running sudo apt-get upgrade, am getting below error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 samba-common
 smbclient
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 ifupdown
 network-manager
 nvidia-common
 samba-common-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.(Follow the steps)

Go to recovery by following the steps :

1. Reboot.
2. Go to "Advanced options for Ubuntu".
3. Select kernel version and its recovery option.
4. Select "Enable networking".
5. Select "Drop to a root shell prompt".
6. Run these commands & reboot.

   ```
   update-initramfs -u
   update-grub2
   ```

If this method does not work and you are unable to go into recovery mode. (Follow the steps)

1. Boot from LiveCD or PenDrive.
2. Run this command in terminal and  check for your ubuntu partition:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```
3. Change the value of **fdisk** with your ubuntu partition ie. (sda1,sad2) and run this commands:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/fdisk /mnt
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
4. Now run these commands in terminal & reboot:

   ```
   update-initramfs
   update-grub
   ```

Note: Once you able to reboot PC you would be able to enter your Ubuntu, after that update the system using `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade` and remove extra packages using `sudo apt autoremove`.